# The React website is not loading the content entered on ReactDOM.render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am beginner to react, and tried to create a simple react page that displayed Hello World. The "Hello World" is not loading.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="root">
        <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/JSX"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<h1>Hello World</h1>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I expected "Hello World" but it is not showing that.

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. I think you haven't setup the module bundling correctly.

Comment: @vighnesh153 thanks for the reply. It says the ReactDOM.render() is no longer supported.

Comment: Aah. You must be using React 18. You need to use ReactDOM.createRoot instead. Check the docs here: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot

Comment: How are you serving your code?